# how to use update message activity in bot framework v3 C#

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

How to implement message update/delete activity in bot framework v3 in c# for MSTeams channel.

Any guidance links/sample code will be helpful.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these docs for [Message update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#updating-messages) and [Message delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#deleting-messages) in a bot using in v3.

Comment: Thanq so much... It was helpful.